# How can I obtain information about the GPU in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to obtain information about the GPU that is running the game in order to use the correct texture compression for that GPU:

```
std::string GPUInfo::getTC()
{
    std::string TC;
    cocos2d::Configuration::getInstance()->gatherGPUInfo();
    if(cocos2d::Configuration::getInstance()->supportsPVRTC())
        TC = ".pvr.ccz";
    else if(cocos2d::Configuration::getInstance()->supportsATITC())
        TC = ".dds";
    else
        TC = ".png";
    CCLOG("Texture compression format -> %s", TC.c_str());
    return TC;
}
```

But this keeps causing this error:

```
call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

Is there another way to obtain details about supporting GPU features on the current device?

Comment: It sounds like you're calling without a context ;) Have you initialized an OpenGL ES context, are you running in the thread that initialized it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at your `AppDelegate::applicationFinishedLaunching` function, it begins with these lines of code:

```
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
if(!glview) {
    glview = GLView::create("My Game");
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

You should check for supported compression after those lines are executed.

Comment: That worked! :D, it seems that the problem was that i was trying to call that in the scene code.